# Producers and Consumers with semaphores and threads

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, consumer, producer

I am currently having issues this code. The only part of the code that is having error is "io_production_report(thread_args[0].Produced, pointer);".

The terminal mentions the error as follows"

```
driver.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
driver.cpp:83:51: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[2]’ to ‘int**’
   83 |     io_production_report(thread_args[0].Produced, pointer);
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~
      |                                                   |
      |                                                   int (*)[2]
In file included from driver.cpp:2:
io.h:49:48: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void io_production_report(int*, int**)’
   49 | void io_production_report(int produced[], int *consumed[]);
      |                                           ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:8: driver.o] Error 1
```

I am having problems implementing an array of pointers.
If anyone can help me that would be great!! :

driver.cpp

```
  // Print Production Report
    int pointer[2][2];
    pointer[0][0]=thread_args[0].Consumed[0]; //Ethel
    pointer[0][1]=thread_args[0].Consumed[1]; //Lucy
    pointer[1][0]=thread_args[1].Consumed[0];
    pointer[1][1]=thread_args[1].Consumed[1];

    io_production_report(thread_args[0].Produced, pointer);  //NEED HELP ON THIS LINE
```

driver.h

```
struct args {
    sem_t *mutexOnBelt;
    sem_t *frogMax;
    sem_t *beltMax;
    sem_t *candiesOnBelt;
    sem_t *produceMax;
    sem_t *consumeMax;

    string *belt;
    int *head;
    int *tail;
    int wait_time;
    int produced;
    string *name;
    int Consumed[2];
    int onBelt[2];
    int Produced[2];
};

int option = 0;
int flagValues[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

io.c

```
/*
 * void io_production_report(int produced[], int *consumed[])
 * Show how many candies of each type produced.  Show how many candies consumed by
 * each consumer.
 * produced[] - count for each ProductType
 * *consumed[] - array of pointers to consumed arrays
 *    e.g. consumed[Lucy] points to an array that is indexed by product name
 */
void io_production_report(int produced[], int *consumed[]) {
  int p, c;  /* array indices */
  int total;

  printf("\nPRODUCTION REPORT\n----------------------------------------\n");

  /* show number produced for each producer / candy type */
  for (p=0; p < ProductTypeN; p++) {
    printf("%s producer generated %d candies\n",
       ProducerNames[p], produced[p]);
  }
  
  /* show number consumed by each consumer */
  for (c=0; c < ConsumerTypeN; c++) {
    printf("%s consumed ", ConsumerNames[c]);
    total = 0;
    for (p=0; p < ProductTypeN; p++) {
      if (p > 0)
    printf(" + ");
      total += consumed[c][p];
      printf("%d %s", consumed[c][p], ProducerAbbrevs[p]);
    }
    printf(" = %d total\n", total);
  }

  printf("Elapsed time %.3f s\n", elapsed_s());
}
```

Comment: `int array[N]` decays to `int*`, `int array[N][M]` decays to `int (*)[M]`, not to `int**`. The compiler shows this fact to you.

Comment: `total += consumed[c][p];` will not work in the way you are expecting. Arrays are flat in the memory. Not knowing the first dimension `consumed[1]` is not what you expect.

Comment: I'm still abit lost. could you show me how to write that?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments you need to make a pointer to the first element of your array, id est: you specify you array[N][M] as int (*)[M], working example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void io_production_report(int (*)[2]);

void io_production_report(int (*consumed)[2]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
        printf("%d\n", consumed[i/2][i%2]);
}

int main(void) {
    int pointer[2][2];
    pointer[0][0]=1; //Ethel
    pointer[0][1]=2; //Lucy
    pointer[1][0]=3;
    pointer[1][1]=4;

    io_production_report(pointer);
}
```